# Impact of Eclipse version on Code version

Tags: java, eclipse

Does the version of Eclipse affect the version of code? Suppose, developers are using different version of Eclipse for same version of code with same version of JDK. Will it cause any issue?

Comment: Eclipse version will not affect the source code version.

Answer (score 1):

No, the version of Eclipse does not matter.

Eclipse has extensive configuration for exactly which version of Java you are targeting. For example see the 'Java > Compiler' settings in the Preferences, and the 'Compiler Settings' in the Properties for a Java project.

You can also tell Eclipse which JRE/JDKs you have installed (see the 'Java > Installed JREs' page in the Preferences). You can run your code using any of these JREs, this is completely separate from the version of Java you are using the run Eclipse itself.

You do need to run a version of Eclipse which understands the version of Java you want to use. So for Java 13 you need to use at lease Eclipse 2019-12.

Of course newer versions of Eclipse contain more tools for helping with Java development and more bug fixes so using an up to date version is recommeneded.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is simply an IDE (Integrated development environment). It combines debugging, compiling and other convenient tools for development. on the other hand, the Java code itself is separate, and you don't necessarily need eclipse to write the code. In fact, a simple text editor is enough. All you need is a file with a java extension (Example: hello.java).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what users share. I'm assuming you're using some sort of SCM, in which case the same project (fully shared) on different versions of the IDE can possibly lead to annoying situations.

There would be no issues in general, as far as producing the code is concerned, except in situations where some versions of IDEs don't support the required Java version (or other features). But I see this more as the user being affected rather than the project/code.

Here's what you should keep in mind:

- Keep IDE project configuration files (such as `.project`, `.settings`, `.classpath`) ignored by your SCM system
- All Java configuration should be based on a build tool. Use Maven/Gradle, etc, and any modern IDE will be able to create a project from its config file. The IDE would derive *local* configuration files which should not be sent back to shared repositories

This way, all developers are free to use whatever IDE (and whatever version) without causing interference, and CI tools will work off build tools' configuration as well.